# word meaning sort of... deceivingly important. seemingly irrelevant but very vital

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning

something that seems very irrelevant at the time but turns out to be extremely useful later on... almost like deceitfully important. an example of this would be like in the Legend of Zelda (if any of y'all are familiar) and the Lost Woods is a wood that you traveled to as a child all of the time as sort of a secret hide out spot. Then when you get older, it turns out that those woods are the entrance to a temple you knew nothing about. I sound so nerdy and I don't care. Do you know what I'm saying though? It's like something so vital, yet seemingly so innocent.

Comment: deceptive, maybe or “hidden in plain sight”

Comment: thank you. i think hidden in plain sight may imply i was even looking for it, though. I mean something that you know where it is, yet find absolutely no importance in it despite it's inevitable utility to you.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are describing the literary device known as a **Chekhov's Gun**. This is a term that comes from a quote by the playwright Anton Chekhov about dramatic necessity. As quoted in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Chekhov%27s_gun&oldid=742020002):

> Remove everything that has no relevance to the story. If you say in
>   the first chapter that there is a rifle hanging on the wall, in the
>   second or third chapter it absolutely must go off. If it's not going
>   to be fired, it shouldn't be hanging there.
>
> — Anton Chekhov

The term now encompasses the situation you describe. As [TV Tropes](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ChekhovsGun) puts it, *Chekhov's Gun*

> has come to mean "an insignificant object that later turns out to be
>   important." [sic]

This is sometimes also called the *gun on the X* (mantlepiece, table, etc.) in reference to examples where a gun is shown early on in a play, film, etc. sitting on *X*, apparently coincidentally, and then later it becomes crucial to the plot.

In your example, the childhood adventures in the Lost Wood are shown (and all other details of childhood omitted), so that when the forest is later important the player recognizes it.

I haven't heard this term used to refer to something in real life, presumably because in real life we encounter things that truly are insignificant all the time. However, you could say that you had previously *overlooked* it, and now *see it in a new light* (for example, the good friend from childhood who you suddenly realize is the love of your life).

Answer (score 0):

How about a *key*?

M-W:

> [*key*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/key): something that
>   gives an explanation or identification or provides a solution, as in
>   *the key to a riddle*

We don't always recognize *keys* immediately for what they are, but they are *keys* nonetheless.

In you example, the "*key*" to which you are referring is literally a *key*, *a means of gaining or preventing entrance* [M-W again] to the temple you knew nothing about.